# Como inserir imagem usando react.js

Tags: javascript, html, imagem, react

Estou começando no react, e como eu faço para inserir uma imagem que fique em cima do meu background, que já é uma imagem? 
O código é esse a seguir:

```
import React from 'react'

import Img from 'react-image'

import teacher1 from "./images/teacher1.jpg"

import Navbar from './Navbar'

const AboutPage = () => {

  return (

    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='header-container flex row center-center full-view' >
      <h1 id="sobre">Esse sistema serve para facilitar o planejamento <br/> da carga horária de cada turma, 
          bem como <br/> horário de aulas, docentes que estão <br/> ministrando aula em determinada hora e sala.</h1>
          <img src="./images/teacher1.jpg"/>
          <img src="./images/teacher2.jpg"/>

    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AboutPage;
```

Tentei inserir duas imagens, mas foi tentativa falha.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta é mais simples do que parece, é praticamente a mesma coisa que tu faz com HTML, porem adicionando o conceito do react.

```
import React from 'react'
import imgagemEscolhida from 'endereco-da-imagem'

export default () => <img src={imgagemEscolhida}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma faz o import da imagem e depois usa ela como se fosse um "componente"

```
import React from 'react'

import Img from 'react-image'

import Teacher1 from "./images/teacher1.jpg"

import Teacher2 from "./images/teacher2.jpg"

import Navbar from './Navbar'

const AboutPage = () => {

  return (

    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='header-container flex row center-center full-view' >
      <h1 id="sobre">Esse sistema serve para facilitar o planejamento <br/> da carga horária de cada turma, 
          bem como <br/> horário de aulas, docentes que estão <br/> ministrando aula em determinada hora e sala.</h1>
          <img src={Teacher1 }/>
          <img src={Teacher2 }/>


    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AboutPage;
```